# How to merge 2 list of objects into 1 with a comparison expression in Automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I need to merge 2 lists of objects into 1 taking some properties from objects in list 1 and some properties from the objects in list 2 using a comparison expression using Automapper

I've tried Automapper.Collection (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) nuget but the default actions are:

- If ID's match will map 1 to 2
- If 2 exists and 1 doesn't add to the collection
- If 1 exists and 2 doesn't remove from the collection

but I only want to map if there is a match, if not I want to ignore the record

```cs
public class Class1
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }
        }

        public class Class2
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

        public class Class3
        {
            public string NewId { get; set; }
            public string NewCode { get; set; }
            public string NewDescription { get; set; }
        }

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class3>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.NewId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.NewCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Code))
                    ;
                cfg.CreateMap<Class2, Class3>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.NewDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
                    ;
            });
            var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

            var class1List = new List<Class1>
            {
                new Class1 {Id = "1", Code = "code1"},
                new Class1 { Id = "2", Code = "code2" },
                new Class1 {Id = "3", Code = "code3"}
            };

            var class2List = new List<Class2>
            {
                new Class2 {Id = "2", Description = "desc2"}
            };

 var class3List = mapper.Map<List<Class3>>(class1List);
            mapper.Map(class2List, class3List);
```

I want that "class3List" at the end contains 3 elements, the element with id "2" must have both code and description.

Answer (score 1):

Automapper might not be the right tool for the task.
Instead of Automapper, you may use a simple LINQ Join statement:

```
var class3List = class1List.Join(class2List, o => o.Id, i => i.Id, (o, i) => new Class3 { NewId = o.Id, NewCode = o.Code, NewDescription = i.Description }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks @wertzui for the response. in my project class1 and class2 doesn't arrive in the same time. first i need to map class1 to class3 then class2 to class3.